# How can I shuffle an array of filenames that have spaces in them?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shuffle

I have an array of filenames that may contain spaces in them.  I am using the `shuf` command but it uses the spaces in the filenames as a delimiter and breaks up the filenames when it shuffles.  Is there a way around this or do I have to abandon the `shuf` command?  Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash

vids=()

vids+=("file with spaces.txt")

for arr in "${vids[@]}"; do
    echo -e "$arr\n"
done

vids=( $(shuf -e "${vids[@]}") )    #shuffle contents of array

for arr in "${vids[@]}"; do
    echo -e "$arr\n"
done

exit 0
```

**Ouput:**

```
file with spaces.txt

file

with

spaces.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your approach doesn't work is that the shell applies word splitting to the output of a command inside `$(...)`, and there's no way to treat newlines as a separator. You could either use `mapfile` to read lines into an array (in Bash 4+):

```
mapfile -t vids < <(shuf -e "${vids[@]}")
```

Or in older versions of Bash you could use good old-fashioned `while` loop:

```
vids2=()
while read -r item; do
    vids2+=("$item")
done < <(shuf -e "${vids[@]}")
```

Comment: Will the second solution also work in newer versions of Bash?  And what does this syntax mean `< <(shuf -e "${vids[@]}")`

Comment: @deanresin It will work in newer versions too. You can read more about `<(...)` in `man bash` in the "Process Substitution" section. `<` right in front of it is input redirection.

Comment: Is it piping every iteration to shuf or the entire array when all the iterations are done?

Comment: @deanresin the loop is reading line by line from the output of the command in `<(...)`

Comment: I much prefer the first solution on second thought because it shuffles them in place.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

@janos has already explained the problem, so I won't duplicate that. But there is another approach to solving the problem: shuffle the array indexes (which are just numbers) rather than the entries themselves, and then copy elements into a new array in the shuffled order:

```
shuffledvids=()
for index in $(shuf -e "${!vids[@]}"); do    # The ! gets the indexes, rather than entries
    shuffledvids+=("${vids[index]}")
done
prinf '%s\n' "${shuffledvids[@]}"    # Another way to print array elements, one per line
```