# Bash: obtaining a shuffled list of filenames-with-spaces on a single line (as argument)?

Tags: bash

Say I have this script, `test.sh`:

```
for ix in "$@"; do
  echo -$ix-;
done
```

EDIT: `test.sh` is merely a stand in for another command line program, say `vlc` - so I need the arguments to it to be correct filenames; I don't need to modify `test.sh` itself!

... and these files:

```
touch "ftest one.mp3"
touch "ftest two.mp3"
touch "ftest three.mp3"
```

I get a correct output if I do this:

```
$ bash test.sh ftest*
-ftest one.mp3-
-ftest three.mp3-
-ftest two.mp3-
```

Now, I'd like to randomize this list - using `shuf`; but in this trivial case, the words are split:

```
$ bash test.sh $(ls ftest* | shuf)
-ftest-
-one.mp3-
-ftest-
-two.mp3-
-ftest-
-three.mp3-
```

If I quote the subprocess part, then I get one giant string - still not what I want:

```
$ bash test.sh "$(ls ftest* | shuf)"
-ftest two.mp3 ftest one.mp3 ftest three.mp3-
```

So, how can I rewrite the subprocess, so when used as argument to `test.sh`, it will deliver correct filenames-with-spaces?

Comment: `bash test.sh *.mp3 | shuf`?

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus - but this `test.sh` is a stand in for another program; I need to get correct files into it as argument

Comment: `cvlc --random *.mp3`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your file names do not contain line breaks.

```
# read files to array "files"
files=(*.mp3)     

# Output array "files", shuffle, read to array "mixed"
mapfile -t mixed < <(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | shuf)

bash test.sh "${mixed[@]}"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
-ftest three.mp3-
-ftest one.mp3-
-ftest two.mp3-
```

Comment: If the filenames might contain newlines (which is perfectly legal in unix), you can shuffle the array indexes instead, as in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737113/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-of-filenames-that-have-spaces-in-them/53737737#53737737).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thank you. I'll take care of it. That's a good idea. The long way without `shuf` would be to randomly select two indexes several times and exchange the contents.